# Child view data not showing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, xcode12.3

I am new in Swift and my code was working fine but I install Xcode 12.3 and since then child view data not showing. My code is like this

```
 private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
            // Add Child View Controller
            addChild(viewController)
            let ScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
            // Add Child View as Subview
            view.addSubview(viewController.view)
           
            // Configure Child View
            viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenSize.width, y: viewController.view.frame.origin.y , width: viewController.view.frame.size.width, height: viewController.view.frame.size.height)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(topView)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(menuView)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(view4Profile)
            topView.layoutIfNeeded()
            var containerFrame = view.bounds
            
            if GlobalConstant.IS_IPHONE_X || GlobalConstant.IS_IPHONE_XSMAX
            {
                containerFrame.origin.y = 90
                containerFrame.size.height = view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.origin.y
            }
            else
            {
                containerFrame.origin.y = topView.frame.size.height
                containerFrame.size.height = view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.origin.y
            }
           viewController.view.frame = containerFrame
           viewController.view.spruce.prepare(with: [.fadeIn, .expand(.slightly)])
           viewController.view.spruce.animate([.fadeIn, .expand(.slightly)])
         
           viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }

  

    public func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
            // Notify Child View Controller
            viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
            
            // Remove Child View From Superview
            viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            
            // Notify Child View Controller
            viewController.removeFromParent()
        }





private lazy var ManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController: ManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController = {
        // Load Storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        // Instantiate View Controller
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController") as! ManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController
        
        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)
        
        return viewController
    }()
```

to call method

```
@objc func gotoManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController()
    {
        view4Profile.isHidden = false
        for controller in self.children
        {
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
            controller.removeFromParent()
        }
        add(asChildViewController: ManagerDashboardTimeSheetViewController)
    }
```

I was able to show Masterview as well as child view. But in Xcode 12.3 when I upload app it is showing blank screen. It's showing master view but not a child view.

Comment: Try changing this line ->
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenSize.width, y: viewController.view.frame.origin.y , width: viewController.view.frame.size.width, height: viewController.view.frame.size.height)
"To"
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: viewController.view.frame.size.width, height: viewController.view.frame.size.height)

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh Still Child view is empty

Comment: try adding some background color to the view so that you can debug whether the bounds are okay and within visible region or is there any issue with the code/adding view controller.

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh It is working fine on device and simulator. But when I test it on testflight it shows nothing just master view not showing content of child view